# Google Big Query SQL Aggregate Data based on Sessions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am currently working with Google Analytics Data in Big Query, and one thing I have yet to be able to wrap my head around is how to write a query to get aggregated data over events from one session. 
I have searched around to find something that might work, but couldn't get it so far. 
Bascially, this is how the table looks (vastly simplified):

```
UserID | event_name | event_timestamp
--------------------------------------
1      | login      | 1543171146125000
1      | other event| 1543171155329000
1      | other event| 1543171155341001
1      | login      | 1543171157796003
1      | other event| 1543171160541000
2      | login      | 1543171157796003
2      | other event| 1543171177531000
```

What I want to do now is aggregating data over User AND session, whereas a session is defined as all events until another login event is shown for that user. 
I'm assuming I have to come up with an additional field "session" that bascially is always showing a new ID once a login event_name is encountered for the currently aggregated UserID.

So, for instance, in that case, if I want to have an aggregated event count, the resulting table would look someting like:

```
UserID | session | EventCount
---------------------------
   1   |    1    |    3
   1   |    2    |    2
   2   |    1    |    2
```

My assumption would be that there is some sub-query I could use to get that magical "session" field, so something like:

```
SELECT UserID, session, COUNT(event_name) as EventCount
FROM (Insert Magical Subquery here)
GROUP BY UserID, session
```

Any ideas how this might be done? It seems like a simple thing but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, a session seems to start with a "login".  So, you can just do a cumulative count "login"s for each `userid`:

```
select t.*,
       countif(event_name = 'login') over (partition by userid order by event_timestamp) as session
from t;
```

You can then aggregate:

```
select userid, session, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             countif(event_name = 'login') over (partition by userid order by event_timestamp) as session
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, session;
```

Comment: This actually does exactly what I want! Thanks a lot for that!
Can't wrap my head aroudn why it works exactly though - would you mind explaining it?